# Wall switch to half hot outlet both standard

Tags: electrical

Why do I have 2 feed lines coming into my switch box both are black, white and ground. Thanks.

Comment: So just two black wires, a white and a round wire... that's it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more details before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: We'd need to know more about what all is going on in the switch box.  Having 2 or 3 cables in a switch box is perfectly common and has good reasons for happening, and we can enlighten you further if you can tell us how they are wired.  *Note that how the wires are already arranged is fairly important; don't tear stuff apart without documenting which is which*.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch and outlet boxes please?

Answer (score 2):

A normal switch with power located at the switch could have two cables coming in with the neutral/white wires are all connected together. Then, the ground wires are all connected with a pigtail to the green screw on the switch. Lastly, one hot/black connects to one switch terminal and the other hot/black to the other switch terminal.

When you turn the switch on power is passed through to the fixture or receptacle. This is quite common.

[image]